Latest Wordpress Version Changes to Block Editor Template
With the latest version of WordPress I noticed that I'm not able to change the template file based on the custom page templates that I've made when I'm on BLOCK EDITOR mode. I am ONLY able to change the template when I switch to CLASSIC EDITOR which requires me to install the classic editor plugin. Before I used to be able to do this just fine in the block editor but after the latest update, the dropdown shows different options now.
Is there any override I can do in functions.php to restore the previous functionality?

Can you share a screenshot of what you're talking about? I'm not familiar with any issues like this. Classic custom page templates should still be selectable in the block editor. Are you using a custom theme.

Hi @JacobPeattie, thanks for replying this is what i meant.
https://ibb.co/XCd3JFH
https://ibb.co/mFRn5vL
